# Convert SAS proc Format to R

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to convert a Proc Format statement in SAS to R.

```
proc format;
    value age_f 0='All Ages' 1='18-24' 2='25-34' 3='35-44' 4='45-54' 5='55-64' 
    6='65+';
```

I've looked in to the factor and the levels in R, but I am not sure how to implement then so I can use the categories later.

Comment: Can you please describe what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [StatMethods](http://www.statmethods.net/input/valuelabels.html) link shows, use the `factor()` method to align value labels to levels:

```
mydata$age_f <- factor(mydata$age_f,
                       levels = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                       labels = c("All Ages", "18-24", "25-34",
                                  "35-44", "45-54", "55-64"))
```

Comment: Please note that I agree with Parfait's solution, because it saves memory.
However, I think SAS's proc format creates a character variable. You could do this with a lookup-table.    
     lookup.vec<-c('0'='All Ages','1'='18-24','2'='25-34','3'='35-44',
              '4'='45-54','5'='55-64','6'='65+')
     (age.vec<-as.character(c(0,2,3,2,3,6)))
     (age.vec<-unname(lookup.vec[age.vec]))

Comment: Formats don't necessarily change anything, except how the data is viewed. The underlying data may be numeric or character, in the original format.